# cURL command equivalent in java program

Tags: java, jsp, curl

I have a cURL command from icescrum API for authentication, and want to know its equivalent java program to use in a jsp page.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -u yourUsername:yourPassword \
     --verbose http://domain/icescrum/ws/p/YOURPROJ/story
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use HttpClient in your case, as it appears that you are trying to make http calls using curl. [Link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) for using HttpClient.

Comment: I downloaded it but there isn't any mention to curl neither in tutorial nor the example :(

Comment: That's right.  There is no "curl" command in HttpClient.  You use HttpClient instead of a "curl" command.  Read the tutorials.

Comment: Right Stephen. HttpClient is used to make http calls and it is widely used in enterprise software's as well.

Comment: but my problem is with adding the arguments to it i saw a couple of codes around the net with different approaches i want to now the simple code snippet for these special arguments here like -u --verbose,etc